# How can I make a Player only look in one direction?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map for Minecraft and I want to make the Player only be able to face a certain wall.

**Is there any way that I could do that?**

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with the  `/tp` repeating. For example:

```
/tp @p ~ ~ ~ 90 0
```

The `~ ~ ~` means that their `x`, `y` and `z` won't be changed, but their `yaw` (left/right) will be set to `90` and their `pitch` (up/down) to 0.

You will need to put this command in a repeating command block or some other form of clock.

Comment: Is it possible to make it so if they turn it won't let them in general, like instead of them going back to 90 degrees, it just won't let them turn at all?

Comment: @ML8awesome I got another solution, where you can't SEE what's behind you, but you CAN turn. Yay!

Comment: Ok that could work, but I don't really care if the player sees what's behind them. I just don't want the player to look down because there are barriers and I don't want the player to see them.

Comment: Also, do you know if there is anyway to make barriers fully invisible with no outline?

Comment: adventure mode. testfor barrier under player and set them into gamemode a

Comment: @ML8awesome if you use a repeating command block (as introduced in 1.9) they won't be able to look around, since the command is run 20 times every second. In contrast the eye can only see at 40ish FPS, so they won't be able to see much movement.